# Antlr 4 Generate Parse Tree Code in Java

Tags: java, sql, parsing, antlr, antlr4

Using Antlr4, I want to generate the parse tree in the form of Java/JavaScript code. 
This is what my main.Java looks like

```
 String sql = "SELECT log AS x FROM t1 \n" +
                "GROUP BY x\n" +
                "HAVING count(*) >= 4 \n" +
                "ORDER BY max(n) + 0";

        // Create a lexer and parser for the input.
        SQLiteLexer lexer = new SQLiteLexer(new ANTLRInputStream(sql));
        SQLiteParser parser = new SQLiteParser(new CommonTokenStream(lexer));

        // Invoke the `select_stmt` production.
        ParseTree tree = parser.select_stmt();
        ParseTreeWalker walker = new ParseTreeWalker();
        SQLiteListener listener = new SQLiteBaseListener();
        ParseTreeWalker.DEFAULT.walk(listener, tree);
    System.out.println(listener.);
```

What function should I invoke to generate the parse tree in code format?

Comment: Can you give an example what you want to see on standard out?

Comment: @StefanA -I wanted the parse tree in the form ofhierarchical java classes.

Comment: "hierarchical java classes" doesn't make sense without more context. Do you mean that you want to get an AST? You need to create the Java classes and build the AST manually. That's the only thing I can think that seems related to what you asked.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure what you meant by "hierarchical" view. There is -gui option with antlr command line tool if that is that is what you are looking for. Otherwise, you can print how the grammar is evaluated by adding Actions and/or add Sysouts in the enter/exist listener methods created by ANTLR. For example, if you have the following grammer:

```
grammar Grammar;

@lexer::header{
 //package name where Java files will be created
}

@parser::header{
//package name where Java files will be created
}


value  : letters | number | string;

letters : LETTERS;
number  : NUMBER;
string  : STRING;

LETTERS : '/*' {System.out.println("Found Letters!");};
NUMBER  : [0-9]+ {System.out.println("Found Number!");};
STRING : [a-zA-Z0-9]+ {System.out.println("Found String!");};

WS : [ \t\r\n]+ -> skip ; // skip spaces, tabs, newlines
```

ANTLR4 will generate a *GrammarListener.java* (assuming that your grammar is called Grammar.g4)  if you run right click the .g4 file in Eclipse and select "Generate ANTLR Recognizer" with ANTRL4 IDE installed. You can also generate the parser and lexer using Java by calling the static *org.antlr.v4.Tool.main*:

```
Tool.main(new String[]{grammarFile, "-o", outputDirectory});
```

The generated interface will contain methods like as follows:

```
public interface GrammarListener extends ParserTreeListener {
    void enterValue(GrammarParser.Valuecontext ctx);
    void exitValue(GrammarParser.ValueContext ctx);
    void enterLetters(GrammarParser.StringContext ctx);
    void exitLetters(GrammarParser.StringContext ctx);
    .
    .
}
```

You would need to implement this interface...

```
public class GrammarListenerImpl implements GrammarListener {

.
.
@Override
public void enterLetters(GrammarParser.LetterContext ctx) {
 System.out.println("Enter: Letters");
// do other stuff
.
.
}
```

and add Sysouts, in this case, or other business logic to handle when this match occurs in the grammar. The Sysouts can generate something like:

```
Enter value
   Enter Letters
     Do something...
   Exit Letters
Exit value
```

This would show a nested (format it with tab/space etc.) the call sequence in which the grammar is evaluated.

Comment: A good answer, but it miss the code that aim to execute the listener and the associated Sysout.

Answer (score 0):

This line:

```
ParseTree tree = parser.select_stmt();
```

is your parse tree. Checkout the API docs to see what method it has: http://www.antlr.org/api/JavaTool/org/antlr/v4/runtime/tree/ParseTree.html

You'll probably be interested in its `getChild(...)` and `getParent()` methods.

Comment: Thanks Bart, I am using this method. I was wondering if this parse tree can be viewed in the form of hierarchical java classies.

Comment: Hi @user3898179, not sure what you mean by "hierarchical java class". My understanding of `ParseTree` is just that: a Java class with parent and child nodes you can access (i.e. a "hierarchical java class").